# When did jerseys get dots on them?

Tags: uniform

I thought jerseys have last names (or nothing) on the back of them. However, I recently saw dots on a jersey.

[image: dots on jersey]

When did jerseys get dots on them? What do they represent? It sorta looks like scoreboard dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), the writing system for visually impaired people.

The letters spell B-U-N-D-Y, so it's probably [Dylan Bundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_Bundy), who plays with #37 for the Orioles.

Comment: Context: [The National Federation for the Blind moved its HQ to Baltimore in 1978](https://www.mlb.com/cut4/the-orioles-wore-braille-jerseys/c-295144612).

Comment: Summing up @PhilipKendall comment in case you don’t click -the Orioles are the first team ever to do this and it is indeed Braille.